# Database optional parameter error

Tags: sql, database, mule

I was having issues with my dynamic query because I have some null values. I have made the values optional if it doesn't have any value but I'm still getting the error. any thoughts?

This is my dynamic query on the database connector. I think the issue is on the BROKER and COTTON org statement

```
insert into [AWH_PrjPathFinder].[dbo].[ws_balesDataExt] values ('#[payload['FULLDATE']]', '#[payload.BROKER = (payload['BROKER'] == null) ? '' : payload.BROKER.toString()]', '#[payload.CENTER = ( payload['CENTER'] == null) ? '' : payload.CENTER.toString()]', '#[payload.DATATYPE = ( payload['DATATYPE'] == null) ? '' : payload.DATATYPE.toString()]','#[payload.COTTONORG = (payload['COTTONORG'] == null) ? '' : payload.COTTONORG.toString()]',#[payload['UNIT']],'#[payload['dateDataEnteredInAGDB']]')
```

this is my sample input file.

```
[ {
"FULLDATE": "28/09/2015",
"CENTER": "B",
"DATATYPE": "CDLV",
"UNIT": "195" },
{
"FULLDATE": "28/09/2015",
"CENTER": "M",
"DATATYPE": "CRCV",
"UNIT": "47"
},
{
"FULLDATE": "28/09/2015",
"CENTER": "M",
"DATATYPE": "CRCV",
"UNIT": "60"
},
{
"FULLDATE": "28/09/2015",
"CENTER": "M",
"DATATYPE": "DDMP",
"UNIT": "84"
 },
 {
 "FULLDATE": "28/09/2015",
"CENTER": "M",
"DATATYPE": "DRCV",
"UNIT": "24"
  },
```

Comment: You should list all the columns being inserted in an `insert` statement.

Comment: Still getting what error?

Comment: add the error message (in full) & in future, when dealing with errors, do this without us having to ask please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always specify the columns (in the correct order) when forming inserts (& this point made by Gordon Linoff).

e.g. (the second line below has been added - it is a guess)

```
INSERT INTO [AWH_PrjPathFinder].[dbo].[ws_balesDataExt] 
    ([FULLDATE],[BROKER],[CENTER],[DATATYPE],[COTTONORG],[UNIT],[dateDataEnteredInAGDB])
VALUES 
      (   '#[payload['FULLDATE']]'
        , '#[payload.BROKER = (payload['BROKER'] == null) ? '' : payload.BROKER.toString()]'
        , '#[payload.CENTER = ( payload['CENTER'] == null) ? '' : payload.CENTER.toString()]'
        , '#[payload.DATATYPE = ( payload['DATATYPE'] == null) ? '' : payload.DATATYPE.toString()]'
        , '#[payload.COTTONORG = (payload['COTTONORG'] == null) ? '' : payload.COTTONORG.toString()]'
        , '#[payload['UNIT']]
        , '#[payload['dateDataEnteredInAGDB']]'
      )
```